# How to check user input in a simple number guessing game?

Tags: java

I have to check if the user's input is a int and within range of 1-100. I know I have to use the input.hasNextInt() function but I can't seem to correctly place it in the code. I am new to programming and I will appreciate it if someone can give me any other tips or suggestions on what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartA {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int numberToGuess = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("I'm thinking of a number. Guess a value (1-100): ");
        int guessNumber = input.nextInt();

        boolean win = false;
        while (win == false){

             numberOfTries++;


             if (guessNumber < numberToGuess) 
             {
                 System.out.print("Too Low.  Guess again: ");
                 guessNumber = input.nextInt();
             }
             else if (guessNumber > numberToGuess) 
             {
                 System.out.print("Too High.  Guess again: ");
                 guessNumber = input.nextInt();
             } 
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Correct!  You got it in " + numberOfTries + " tries.");
                 win = true;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run this code.Looks good so far.why u need input.hasNextInt()?

Answer (score 0):

Following changes would help in the right operation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        int numberToGuess = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        System.out
                .print("I'm thinking of a number. Guess a value (1-100): ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean win = false;
        do {
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {    //Handle non-integer entry
                input.next();
                System.out.println("Expecting a number. Try again.");
            }
            int guessNumber = input.nextInt();
            numberOfTries++;
            if (guessNumber < numberToGuess) {
                System.out.print("Too Low.  Guess again: ");
                // guessNumber = input.nextInt(); - Reading in a single
                // place
            } else if (guessNumber > numberToGuess) {
                System.out.print("Too High.  Guess again: ");
                // guessNumber = input.nextInt(); - Reading in a single
                // place, above
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct!  You got it in "
                        + numberOfTries + " tries.");
                win = true;
            }
        } while (!win);
    } finally {
        input.close(); // Closing the scanner stream
    }
}
```